What hypothesis testing method should I use for comparing binned latency counts
I am trying to select a proper hypothesis testing method for testing if the latency is higher in a group of servers is higher than another group. However, all what I have is just counts for a number of latency bins, and I do not access to the original latency values. The data look like below




[0, 0.01)
[0.01, 0.05)
[0.05, 1)
...




Group 1
$n_{11}$
$n_{12}$
$n_{13}$
...


Group 2
$n_{21}$
$n_{22}$
$n_{23}$
...



where the columns are the latency bins with unit of being second, and $n_{ij}$ shows the number of requests recorded for (group, latency bin) pair.
Initially, I was thinking of using Pearson's $\chi^2$ test, but that does not take into consideration the bins are ordered. Also it's unclear how to do a directed test with $\chi^2$ test. Any recommendation for a better one?

You could use a Mann-Whitney U test (MWUt), with the null hypothesis that $P(Group1>Group2)=.5$; the alternative can then be directional (e.g. $P(Group1>Group2)>.5)$, which would indicate that Group1 has, more often than not, a larger latency than Group2 (swap the groups if the data shows the inequality being the other way), which seems to be exactly what you want to show. The MWUt works perfectly for ordinal data (what you have), is non-parametric, and for the null I mentioned, requires no additional assumption from your data. As you will have a large number of "ties" (i.e. $min(m_{1j}, m_{2j})$, for all j's) your software needs to account for this properly (most -all?- software packages do this).
You could also run a median test (Mood's median test), which in the end is a $\chi^2$). and can be directional. But it only tests for equality of medians: one can very easily construct examples of samples where the medians are exactly equal, but the MWUt is significant. IT is also usually less powerful than the MWUt. So I would only do this test after a significant MWUt, to see if the medians are different (they may not be), and in the same direction (they may also not be). This would explain part of the reasons of why the MWUt is significant (the entire comparative shapes of the distributions play a role, not just some measure of centrality like the median.
Last you could also compute a "pseudo-mean"; assign to each bin the mid-point of the interval (e.g. .005, .02, .075, etc. in your example), and then replace the counts by $n_{ij}$ values; then run a 2-sample Welch t-test to compare the means. You could even go 1 step further, by chosing (arbitrarily?) a probability density function (uniform, normal, beta, ?) and generate $n_{ij}$ samples accordingly for each bin. Note that whether this approach would be formally correct is very debatable; I am "upgrading" the data from ordinal to ratio scale (valid?), by some arbitrary method (valid?), and the resulting 2 distributions will most likely be anything but normal (is t-test valid?). I may just try that, to see if it gives me an answer consistent with the MWUt, just as a sanity check; if it does, I would not even mention this pseudo-mean. If it does not, then I would look much more carefully at the data to understand why the different results (and I may dismiss that result in the end anyway).
TL;DR: MWUt

MWUt doesn't seem to make sense, that P(group 1 > group2 = 0.5) can't be interpreted as the latency of group 1 is higher than group 2.

@zyxue, the U statistic looks at all possible pair-wise comparisons between the 2 samples: add 1 if Group1 one "wins" (latency is larger) and .5 if there is a tie. You then compare this U score to tables of critical values. A significant results means Group 1 wins (i.e. has longer latency) significantly more often than Group 2. This is exactly what you seem to need? The short hand notation means that the probability that a random value taken from Group 1 is larger than a random value picked from Group 2 is > .05; overall, Group 1 has longer latency, i.e. is stochastically greater.

@zyxue, e.g. take a look here: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_04.html, or here https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/what-is-mann-whitney-u-test/, and you will see that, if the MWUt is significant, then 1 group has, more often than not, longer latency, QFD...

I think I have a reasonable idea how MWUt works, what would be the input to the test by your approach?

Exactly the data you have; label your bins as "1,2,3,..." (it does not really matter exactly how you label them, as long as the order is preserved; you could use the low bound of the intervals, the midpoint of the intervals, etc.), and have 2 samples, each with $n_{ij}$ values per bin: n11 values=1, n12 values=2, etc, for group 1, same for group 2 (n21 values=1, n22 values=2, etc...).

I am not sure why that  is useful? Suppose if all values (nij) in group 1 is larger than that in group 2, MWUt returns a significant p-value, how would you interpret the output, which group has higher latency? Note, the intuition for higher latency is that within a group if more requests fall into the higher bins, it's not really about the absolute counts, more about the proportions.

"suppose all $n_{ij}$ values are in group 1 are larger than that in group 2, MWUt will return a significant p-value". No, it will not. Just do a quick simulation: only 2 levels (j=1 or 2). 20 1's and 20 2's for group1, 5 (or 10) 1's and 2's for group 2. The p-value will be 1.000 (because the proportions are identical).  Add a few 2's to group 1 (or a few 1's to group 2), and you will see the p-value drop. This is because the U statistic adds all possible pair-wise comparisons. Group 1 wins more often because it has more 2', but also loses more often because it has more 1's.

I think I see what you mean now. Basically, 1) score the bins; 2). convert the count in each cell to a count-size sample by repeating the corresponding bin score count times; 3). combine the samples of each bin for both group 1 and group 2; 4). apply MWUt for the two samples of group 1 and group 2. Do I understand correctly?

Exactly! Imagine how the data was acquired; a single latency event was observed; it was compared to each of the bins. Which ever bin it happened to fall into, +1 was added to the count for that bin. Well, instead you "unwrap" this count; insted of adding 1 to a count, you just add 1 more "bin score" to the sample.  You now have a sample of ordinal values, of size $Sum(n_{1j})$ for group1. Same for group2. MWUt will give you the answer you seek.

Do you have any intuition on how MWUt would compare to a method like Mantel-Haenszel (MH) statistic?

MH is a test of association, similar to $\chi^2$. It will not tell you that one group is "greater" than the other, just that the observed counts are linearly associated. That does not seem to be what you are after; "testing if the latency is higher in a group of servers"?
